# how to get data out of firestore into a string

Tags: java, android

I have created a collection in firebase how can I retrieve a field out of it?

[image: Image For Reference]

In this image how can I get mail into a string using java in android?

```
FirebaseFirestore store = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

DocumentReference ref = store.collection("admin").document("nefEFEQGuQOl3RqhHmjnVbHvt133");

ref.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
        Map<String, Object> data = documentSnapshot.getData();
        String mail= (String) data.get("mail");
        Toast.makeText(login_admin.this, mail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mail: " + mail);
      } else {
         Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
        }
  }
});
```

I am trying to get a data snapshot of the collection but not getting the mail out of it.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong here? onSuccess() is not being called or what?